# Good source of Crawler / Spider IP addresses

Tags: ip, web-crawler

Where could I find comprehensive list of Crawler or Spider IP address. I need IPs from google yahoo microsoft and other search engines that regularly crawl my sites.

I do not want to disable them so keep robots.txt file out of the answers. The list is for filter that is doing statistical reporting on activity on each page.

Please post links to good sources that could be used. Paid or free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your web server logs.  I believe they're free.

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't want to do this by IP address. Most crawlers send a unique user agent string when they crawl your site and it's much more likely you want to use that to identify them. I don't know where you can find a good list of those though

EDIT: Actually [this](http://www.jafsoft.com/searchengines/webbots.html) page I found with google seems to both answer your question a bit, and also give the user agents (which is still more likely a better approach)

Answer (score 3):

**>> [Updated list](https://github.com/monperrus/crawler-user-agents/blob/master/crawler-user-agents.json) <<**

List as at Jan 16, 2016

```
[
  {
    "pattern": "googlebot\\/", 
    "url": "http://www.google.com/bot.html"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "Googlebot-Mobile"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "Googlebot-Image"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "Mediapartners-Google", 
    "url": "https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "bingbot", 
    "url": "http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "slurp", 
    "url": "http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "java"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "wget"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "curl"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "Commons-HttpClient"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "Python-urllib"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "libwww"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "httpunit"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "nutch"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "phpcrawl", 
    "addition_date": "2012-09/17", 
    "url": "http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "msnbot", 
    "url": "http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "jyxobot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "FAST-WebCrawler"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "FAST Enterprise Crawler"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "biglotron"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "teoma"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "convera"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "seekbot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "gigablast",
    "instances": ["Gigabot/2.0 (http://www.gigablast.com/spider.html)", "Gigabot/2.0 (http://www.gigablast.com/spider.html)", "GigablastOpenSource/1.0"],
    "url": "https://github.com/gigablast/open-source-search-engine"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "exabot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "ngbot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "ia_archiver"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "GingerCrawler"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "webmon "
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "httrack"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "webcrawler"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "grub.org"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "UsineNouvelleCrawler"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "antibot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "netresearchserver"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "speedy"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "fluffy"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "bibnum.bnf"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "findlink"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "msrbot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "panscient"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "yacybot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "AISearchBot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "IOI"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "ips-agent"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "tagoobot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "MJ12bot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "dotbot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "woriobot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "yanga"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "buzzbot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "mlbot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "yandexbot",
    "url": "http://yandex.com/bots",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/04/14"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "purebot", 
    "addition_date": "2010/01/19"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "Linguee Bot", 
    "addition_date": "2010/01/26", 
    "url": "http://www.linguee.com/bot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "Voyager", 
    "addition_date": "2010/02/01", 
    "url": "http://www.kosmix.com/crawler.html"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "CyberPatrol", 
    "addition_date": "2010/02/11", 
    "url": "http://www.cyberpatrol.com/cyberpatrolcrawler.asp"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "voilabot", 
    "addition_date": "2010/05/18"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "baiduspider", 
    "addition_date": "2010/07/15", 
    "url": "http://www.baidu.jp/spider/"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "citeseerxbot", 
    "addition_date": "2010/07/17"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "spbot", 
    "addition_date": "2010/07/31", 
    "url": "http://www.seoprofiler.com/bot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "twengabot", 
    "addition_date": "2010/08/03", 
    "url": "http://www.twenga.com/bot.html"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "postrank", 
    "addition_date": "2010/08/03", 
    "url": "http://www.postrank.com"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "turnitinbot", 
    "addition_date": "2010/09/26", 
    "url": "http://www.turnitin.com"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "scribdbot", 
    "addition_date": "2010/09/28", 
    "url": "http://www.scribd.com"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "page2rss", 
    "addition_date": "2010/10/07", 
    "url": "http://www.page2rss.com"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "sitebot", 
    "addition_date": "2010/12/15", 
    "url": "http://www.sitebot.org"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "linkdex", 
    "addition_date": "2011/01/06", 
    "url": "http://www.linkdex.com"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "Adidxbot", 
    "url": "http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/hh204496.aspx"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "blekkobot", 
    "url": "http://blekko.com/about/blekkobot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "ezooms", 
    "addition_date": "2011/04/27", 
    "url": "http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=935605&start=450#p12948289"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "dotbot", 
    "addition_date": "2011/04/27"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "Mail.RU_Bot", 
    "addition_date": "2011/04/27",
    "instances" : [
      "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Linux x86_64; Mail.RU_Bot/2.0; +http://go.mail.ru/",
      "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Mail.RU_Bot/2.0; +http://go.mail.ru/"
    ]
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "discobot", 
    "addition_date": "2011/05/03", 
    "url": "http://discoveryengine.com/discobot.html"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "heritrix", 
    "addition_date": "2011/06/21", 
    "url": "http://crawler.archive.org/"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "findthatfile", 
    "addition_date": "2011/06/21", 
    "url": "http://www.findthatfile.com/"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "europarchive.org", 
    "addition_date": "2011/06/21", 
    "url": ""
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "NerdByNature.Bot", 
    "addition_date": "2011/07/12", 
    "url": "http://www.nerdbynature.net/bot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "sistrix crawler", 
    "addition_date": "2011/08/02"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "ahrefsbot", 
    "addition_date": "2011/08/28"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "Aboundex", 
    "addition_date": "2011/09/28", 
    "url": "http://www.aboundex.com/crawler/"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "domaincrawler", 
    "addition_date": "2011/10/21"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "wbsearchbot", 
    "addition_date": "2011/12/21", 
    "url": "http://www.warebay.com/bot.html"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "summify", 
    "addition_date": "2012/01/04", 
    "url": "http://summify.com"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "ccbot", 
    "addition_date": "2012/02/05", 
    "url": "http://www.commoncrawl.org/bot.html"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "edisterbot", 
    "addition_date": "2012/02/25"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "seznambot", 
    "addition_date": "2012/03/14"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "ec2linkfinder", 
    "addition_date": "2012/03/22"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "gslfbot", 
    "addition_date": "2012/04/03"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "aihitbot", 
    "addition_date": "2012/04/16"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "intelium_bot", 
    "addition_date": "2012/05/07"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "facebookexternalhit", 
    "addition_date": "2012/05/07"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "yeti", 
    "addition_date": "2012/05/07"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "RetrevoPageAnalyzer", 
    "addition_date": "2012/05/07"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "lb-spider", 
    "addition_date": "2012/05/07"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "sogou", 
    "addition_date": "2012/05/13", 
    "url": "http://www.sogou.com/docs/help/webmasters.htm#07"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "lssbot", 
    "addition_date": "2012/05/15"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "careerbot", 
    "addition_date": "2012/05/23", 
    "url": "http://www.career-x.de/bot.html"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "wotbox", 
    "addition_date": "2012/06/12", 
    "url": "http://www.wotbox.com"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "wocbot", 
    "addition_date": "2012/07/25", 
    "url": "http://www.wocodi.com/crawler"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "ichiro", 
    "addition_date": "2012/08/28", 
    "url": "http://help.goo.ne.jp/help/article/1142"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "DuckDuckBot", 
    "addition_date": "2012/09/19", 
    "url": "http://duckduckgo.com/duckduckbot.html"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "lssrocketcrawler", 
    "addition_date": "2012/09/24"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "drupact", 
    "addition_date": "2012/09/27", 
    "url": "http://www.arocom.de/drupact"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "webcompanycrawler", 
    "addition_date": "2012/10/03"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "acoonbot", 
    "addition_date": "2012/10/07", 
    "url": "http://www.acoon.de/robot.asp"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "openindexspider", 
    "addition_date": "2012/10/26", 
    "url": "http://www.openindex.io/en/webmasters/spider.html"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "gnam gnam spider", 
    "addition_date": "2012/10/31"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "web-archive-net.com.bot"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "backlinkcrawler", 
    "addition_date": "2013/01/04"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "coccoc", 
    "addition_date": "2013/01/04", 
    "url": "http://help.coccoc.vn/"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "integromedb", 
    "addition_date": "2013/01/10", 
    "url": "http://www.integromedb.org/Crawler"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "content crawler spider", 
    "addition_date": "2013/01/11"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "toplistbot", 
    "addition_date": "2013/02/05"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "seokicks-robot", 
    "addition_date": "2013/02/25"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "it2media-domain-crawler", 
    "addition_date": "2013/03/12"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "ip-web-crawler.com", 
    "addition_date": "2013/03/22"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "siteexplorer.info", 
    "addition_date": "2013/05/01"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "elisabot", 
    "addition_date": "2013/06/27"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "proximic", 
    "addition_date": "2013/09/12", 
    "url": "http://www.proximic.com/info/spider.php"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "changedetection", 
    "addition_date": "2013/09/13", 
    "url": "http://www.changedetection.com/bot.html"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "blexbot", 
    "addition_date": "2013/10/03", 
    "url": "http://webmeup-crawler.com/"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "arabot", 
    "addition_date": "2013/10/09"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "WeSEE:Search", 
    "addition_date": "2013/11/18"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "niki-bot", 
    "addition_date": "2014/01/01"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "CrystalSemanticsBot", 
    "addition_date": "2014/02/17", 
    "url": "http://www.crystalsemantics.com/user-agent/"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "rogerbot", 
    "addition_date": "2014/02/28", 
    "url": "http://moz.com/help/pro/what-is-rogerbot-"
  }, 
  {
    "pattern": "360Spider", 
    "addition_date": "2014/03/14", 
    "url": "http://needs-be.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-to-block-spider360.html"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "psbot",
    "addition_date": "2014/03/31",
    "url": "http://www.picsearch.com/bot.html"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "InterfaxScanBot",
    "addition_date": "2014/03/31",
    "url": "http://scan-interfax.ru"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "Lipperhey SEO Service",
    "addition_date": "2014/04/01",
    "url": "http://www.lipperhey.com/"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "CC Metadata Scaper",
    "addition_date": "2014/04/01",
    "url": "http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Metadata_Scraper"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "g00g1e.net",
    "addition_date": "2014/04/01",
    "url": "http://www.g00g1e.net/"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "GrapeshotCrawler",
    "addition_date": "2014/04/01",
    "url": "http://www.grapeshot.co.uk/crawler.php"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "urlappendbot",
    "addition_date": "2014/05/10",
    "url": "http://www.profound.net/urlappendbot.html"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "brainobot",
    "addition_date": "2014/06/24"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "fr-crawler",
    "addition_date": "2014/07/31",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; fr-crawler/1.1)"]
  },
  {
    "pattern": "binlar",
    "addition_date": "2014/09/12",
    "instances": [
      "binlar_2.6.3 binlar2.6.3@unspecified.mail",
      "binlar_2.6.3 binlar_2.6.3@unspecified.mail",
      "binlar_2.6.3 larbin2.6.3@unspecified.mail",
      "binlar_2.6.3 phanendra_kalapala@McAfee.com",
      "binlar_2.6.3 test@mgmt.mic"
    ]
  },
  {
    "pattern": "SimpleCrawler",
    "addition_date": "2014/09/12",
    "instances": ["SimpleCrawler/0.1" ]
  },
  {
    "pattern": "Livelapbot",
    "addition_date": "2014/09/12",
    "instances": ["Livelapbot/0.1" ]
  },
  {
    "pattern": "Twitterbot",
    "addition_date": "2014/09/12",
    "instances": ["Twitterbot/0.1", "Twitterbot/1.0" ]
  },
  {
    "pattern": "cXensebot",
    "addition_date": "2014/10/05",
    "instances": ["cXensebot/1.1a"],
    "url": "http://www.cxense.com/bot.html"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "smtbot",
    "addition_date": "2014/10/04",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SMTBot/1.0; +http://www.similartech.com/smtbo)t", "SMTBot (similartech.com/smtbot)"],
    "url": "http://www.similartech.com/smtbot"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "bnf.fr_bot",
    "addition_date": "2014/11/18",
    "url": "http://www.bnf.fr/fr/outils/a.dl_web_capture_robot.html",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bnf.fr_bot; +http://www.bnf.fr/fr/outils/a.dl_web_capture_robot.html)"]    
  },
  {
    "pattern": "A6-Indexer",
    "addition_date": "2014/12/05",
    "url": "http://www.a6corp.com/a6-web-scraping-policy/",
    "instances": ["A6-Indexer"]    
  },
  {
    "pattern": "ADmantX",
    "addition_date": "2014/12/05",
    "url": "http://www.admantx.com",
    "instances": ["ADmantX Platform Semantic Analyzer - ADmantX Inc. - www.admantx.com - support@admantx.com"]    
  },
  {
    "pattern": "Facebot",
    "url": "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#crawl",
    "addition_date": "2014/12/30"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "Twitterbot",
    "url": "https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started",
    "addition_date": "2014/12/30"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "OrangeBot",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; OrangeBot/2.0; support.orangebot@orange.com"],
    "addition_date": "2015/01/12"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "memorybot",
    "url": "http://mignify.com/bot.htm",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; memorybot/1.21.14 +http://mignify.com/bot.html)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/02/01"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "AdvBot",
    "url": "http://advbot.net/bot.html",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AdvBot/2.0; +http://advbot.net/bot.html)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/02/01"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "MegaIndex",
    "url": "https://www.megaindex.ru/?tab=linkAnalyze",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +https://www.megaindex.ru/?tab=linkAnalyze)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/03/28"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "SemanticScholarBot",
    "url": "http://s2.allenai.org/bot.html",
    "instances": ["SemanticScholarBot/1.0 (+http://s2.allenai.org/bot.html)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/03/28"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "ltx71",
    "url": "http://ltx71.com/",
    "instances": ["ltx71 - (http://ltx71.com/)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/04/04"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "nerdybot",
    "url": "http://nerdybot.com/",
    "instances": ["nerdybot"],
    "addition_date": "2015/04/05"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "xovibot",
    "url": "http://www.xovibot.net/",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; XoviBot/2.0; +http://www.xovibot.net/)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/04/05"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "BUbiNG",
    "url": "http://law.di.unimi.it/BUbiNG.html",
    "instances": ["BUbiNG (+http://law.di.unimi.it/BUbiNG.html)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/04/06"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "Qwantify",
    "url": "https://www.qwant.com/",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Qwantify/2.0n; +https://www.qwant.com/)/*"],
    "addition_date": "2015/04/06"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "archive.org_bot",
    "url": "http://www.archive.org/details/archive.org_bot",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; archive.org_bot +http://www.archive.org/details/archive.org_bot)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/04/14"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "Applebot",
    "url": "http://www.apple.com/go/applebot",
    "addition_date": "2015/04/15"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "TweetmemeBot",
    "url": "http://datasift.com/bot.html",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (TweetmemeBot/4.0; +http://datasift.com/bot.html) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"],
    "addition_date": "2015/04/15"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "crawler4j",
    "url": "https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j",
    "instances": ["crawler4j (http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/05/07"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "findxbot",
    "url": "http://www.findxbot.com",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Findxbot/1.0; +http://www.findxbot.com)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/05/07"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "SemrushBot",
    "url": "http://www.semrush.com/bot.html",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/0.98~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/05/26"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "yoozBot",
    "url": "http://yooz.ir",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; yoozBot-2.2; http://yooz.ir; info@yooz.ir)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/05/26"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "lipperhey",
    "url": "http://www.lipperhey.com/",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Lipperhey Link Explorer; http://www.lipperhey.com/)", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Lipperhey SEO Service; http://www.lipperhey.com/)", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Lipperhey Site Explorer; http://www.lipperhey.com/)", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Lipperhey-Kaus-Australis/5.0; +https://www.lipperhey.com/en/about/)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/08/26"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "y!j-asr",
    "url": "http://www.yahoo-help.jp/app/answers/detail/p/595/a_id/42716/",
    "instances": ["Y!J-ASR/0.1 crawler (http://www.yahoo-help.jp/app/answers/detail/p/595/a_id/42716/)"],
    "addition_date": "2015/05/26"
 },
 {
    "pattern": "Domain Re-Animator Bot",
    "url": "http://domainreanimator.com",
    "instances": ["Domain Re-Animator Bot (http://domainreanimator.com) - support@domainreanimator.com"],
    "addition_date": "2015/04/14"
 },
 {
    "pattern": "AddThis",
    "url": "https://www.addthis.com",
    "instances": ["AddThis.com robot tech.support@clearspring.com"],
    "addition_date": "2015/06/02"
 },
 {
    "pattern": "Screaming Frog SEO Spider",
    "url": "http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider",
    "instances": ["Screaming Frog SEO Spider/5.1"],
    "addition_date": "2016/01/08"
 },
 {
    "pattern": "MetaURI",
    "url": "http://www.useragentstring.com/MetaURI_id_17683.php",
    "instances": ["MetaURI API/2.0 +metauri.com"],
    "addition_date": "2016/01/02"
 },
 {
    "pattern": "Scrapy",
    "url": "http://scrapy.org/",
    "instances": ["Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org)"],
    "addition_date": "2016/01/02"
 },
 {
    "pattern": "LivelapBot",
    "url": "http://site.livelap.com/crawler",
    "instances": ["LivelapBot/0.2 (http://site.livelap.com/crawler)"],
    "addition_date": "2016/01/02"
 },
 {
    "pattern": "OpenHoseBot",
    "url": "http://www.openhose.org/bot.html",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; OpenHoseBot/2.1; +http://www.openhose.org/bot.html)"],
    "addition_date": "2016/01/02"
 },
 {
    "pattern": "CapsuleChecker",
    "url": "http://www.capsulink.com/about",
    "instances": ["CapsuleChecker (http://www.capsulink.com/)"],
    "addition_date": "2016/01/02"
 },
 {
    "pattern": "collection@infegy.com",
    "url": "http://infegy.com/",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 collection@infegy.com"],
    "addition_date": "2016/01/03"
 },
 {
    "pattern": "IstellaBot",
    "url": "http://www.tiscali.it/",
    "instances": ["Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; IstellaBot/1.23.15 +http://www.tiscali.it/)"],
    "addition_date": "2016/01/09"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a trivial matter to know the legitimate IPs of web search engines. User agents can be easily spoofed. The best you can do is go through logs manually and observe their behavior. IPs can also change over time and even be spoofed for certain malicious intent.

Comment: Most of the big search engines advise to look for a UA string, AND do a reverse DNS/nslookup on the ip to ensure that it resolves to a certain domain etc. This way you can find the requests which are spoofing a search engine's UA.

Answer (score 1):

Shodan.IO bot ip addresses found are
198.20.69.72 - 198.20.69.79
198.20.69.96 - 198.20.69.103

I'm sure there may be other addresses in use, but these are the ones I found with a little digging...